# Why I can not test python datetime moudle

Tags: python, datetime

I will test python3.7 datetime.date.today method,and got a variable value,but even I comment the today method,It still work.

python 3.7 python is :

1. I find the datetime path first

   ```
   >>> import datetime
   >>> datetime.__file__
   '/usr/local/python3.7/lib/python3.7/datetime.py'
   ```
2. I do this:

   ```
   >>> datetime.date.today()
   datetime.date(2020, 6, 3)
   ```

   date is not inherit from any class,

   ```
    773 class date:
    774     """Concrete date type.
   ```
3. I comment the today method code in date class

   ```
    833  #   @classmethod
    834  #   def today(cls):
    835  #       "Construct a date from time.time()."
    836  #       t = _time.time()
    837  #       return cls.fromtimestamp(t)
   ```
4. I reload the datetime and execute the script,It still have a result

   ```
   >>> import datetime
   >>> datetime.date.today()
   datetime.date(2020, 6, 3)
   ```
5. who can tell me why ?

6.When I reconnect the SecureCRT,The comment code is effect.

thanks

Comment: Have you re-started the python command line session again after commenting out the code?

Comment: why would you mess with the Python standard lib in the first place?

Comment: Please learn what is `inherit` and what is `override`

Comment: **Do not screw with your standard library files.** You are very likely to break things in a way that causes unreproducible errors and can't be practically fixed without reinstalling Python. You don't want to deal with the hassle of that, and we don't want to deal with the unreproducible debugging questions you're likely to ask in the process.

Answer (score 0):

You already imported `datetime` module, try to re-import with [importlib.reload](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload):

```py
from importlib import reload

reload(datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make your own date class:

```
from datetime import date as oldDate

class date(oldDate):
    @classmethod
    def today(cls):
        return 'foo'

x = date.today()
print(x)
```

Output:

```
foo
```